# $a+b\sqrt{2}$ not a root of monic polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

Consider $a+b\sqrt{2}$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}-\mathbb{Z}$ . I need to show that it cannot be a root of any monic polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (possibly complex) roots of $X^2+pX+q$ are $\frac{-p\pm\sqrt{p^2-4q}}{2}$. Conclude (not as obvious as at first glance, perhaps) that $a=-\frac p2$ and $|4b|=\sqrt{2p^2-8q}$. The square root of an integer is either an integer or irrational, hence $2p^2-8q$ is the square of an integer and is even, hence the square of an even integer, hence a multiple of $4$, hence $p$ is even and $a\in\mathbb Z$, contrary to assumption.

Comment: Technically, you also need to prove, that it is not the root of an higher degree polynomial.

Answer (score 4):

**Hints:**

1. Assume $p\in\mathbb Z[t]$ is a monic polynomial, such that $p(a+b\sqrt{2})=0$. Check, that $p(a-b\sqrt{2})=0$.
2. If $x$ and $y$ are roots of monic polynomials in $\mathbb Z$, then so are $xy$ and $x+y$.
3. If $x\in\mathbb Q$ is a root of a monic polynomial over $\mathbb Z$, then $x\in\mathbb Z$.

(By the way, those elements are called *integral elements*)

**EDIT:** How to conclude the solution from this hints:

> Let $a+b\sqrt{2}$ be a root of a monic polynomial, by (1) so is $a-b\sqrt{2}$ and by (2), so are 
>   $$\left(a+b\sqrt{2}\right)+\left(a-b\sqrt{2}\right)=2a$$
>   and
>   $$\left(a+b\sqrt{2}\right)\left(a-b\sqrt{2}\right)=a^2-2b^2$$
>   Since $2a,a^2-2b^2\in\mathbb Q$, it follows, that $2a,a^2-2b^2\in\mathbb Z$ using (3). So $a=\frac{a'}2$ for some $a\in\mathbb Z$ and, since
>   $$8b^2=(2a)^2-4\cdot(a^2-2b^2)\in\mathbb Z$$
>   also $b=\frac{b'}{2}$ for some $b'\in\mathbb Z$. Inserting this into $a^2-2b^2\in\mathbb Z$ yields $4\mid a'^2-2b'^2$. Calculating modulo $4$ shows that, this fails unless both $a'$ and $b'$ are even, so $a,b\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: in your 2nd hint where does $x,y$ come from?

Comment: Strictly speaking, from the field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})=\{a+b\sqrt{2}\mid a,b\in\mathbb Q\}$. More generally from any finite extension of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: +1 Nice hint indeed... *if* the OP can prove hint 2, which ammount to show the set of integral elements is a ring. Let's see what says he.

Comment: @Tomas not getting the idea of how to arrive at contradictions from your hints!

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal: I edited the solution into the answer. However, you need to prove the hints yourself..